# Conditional expressions as arguments to printf

Tags: c, syntax

So i came across the following code in C Language

```
foo() {                     
    int v=10;
    printf("%d %d %d\n", v==10, v=25, v > 20);
}
```

and it returns `0 25 0`
can anybody explain me how and why

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined behavior and sequence points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf("%d %d %d\n", v==10, v=25, v > 20);
```

What you see is undefined behavior becuase the order of evalutaion within `printf()` is not defined.

The output can be explained as(Right to left evaluation)

```
v = 10 and hence v>20 is false so last `%d` prints 0
v = 25 Now v is 25 so second `printf()` prints out 25
```

Then you have

`v ==10` which is false because v is 25 now. This is not a defined order of evaluation and might vary so this is UB

Answer (score 0):

It is evaluated from right to left...

First it evaluates `v > 20` its false so it prints `0`

Next it sets `v=25` an prints it

Next it check if `v is 10`. Its false so it prints 0 (the value of `v` is changed in the above step)

**EDIT**

This is the way your compiler evaluates it but the order of evalaution generally is undefined

Comment: This seems to imply that function parameter evaluations have a defined order which I don't believe is the case in C.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is subject to undefined behavior. Looks like in your platform,

`v > 20` got evaluated first, followed by
`v=25`, followed by
`v==10`.

Which is perfectly standards compliant behavior.

Remember that those expressions could have been evaluated in any order and it would still be standards compliant behavior.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, I don't see a sequence point between the evaluations. Doesn't this make it undefined behaviour?

Comment: @tangrs, It is undefined behavior. I was trying to explain the outcome reported by the OP.

Comment: You should probably indicate that in your last sentence since it could be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler seems to evaluate the function parameters from right to left.

So, `v > 20` is evaluated first, then `v=25` and then `v==10`.

Therefore you get the output `0 25 0`